# Will GetElementPtr work as expected

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am writing llvm code using C++. I have a place in my code where the below scenario happens

```
 1. %117 = phi <2 x double>* [ %105, %aligned ], [ %159, %116 ]
 7. %123 = getelementptr <2 x double>* %117, i32 0
 8. %127 = getelementptr <2 x double>* %123, i32 0
 9. %128 = load <2 x double>* %127
10. %129 = getelementptr <2 x double>* %123, i32 1
11. %130 = load <2 x double>* %129
12. %131 = shufflevector <2 x double> %128, <2 x double> %130, <2 x i32> <i32 1, i32 3>
```

I am trying to compute the same address which should point to same data type twice in lines 7 and 8 with the address parameter value different. Is it safe to do this or will this lead to undefined results?

Answer (score 0):

The instruction

```
%x = getelementptr %anytype* %y, i32 0
```

Is completely meaningless; it's as if you've written (the illegal):

```
%x = %y
```

So yes, both `%123` and `%127` will point to the same memory. It's safe, but redundant: you can just use `%117` directly wherever `%123` or `%127` are used. The only problematic thing in your snippet is that the value numbering is not sequential, but I assume that's just from pasting just parts of the code here.